# div drops down on resize of browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, floating

My Problems lies in the face that when I resize the page the welcome div falls below the profileImg div instead of just resizing. I know this is very basic, but I need some help please.

I have the following screen shots 
specimen A http://grab.by/iwam
specimen B http://grab.by/iwak

and the following code

**wordpress jazz**

```
<div id="container">
    <section id="profileImg">
    </section>
    <section id="welcome">
    <?php
    // The Query
    query_posts( 'category_name=welcome' );

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content();?></p>
    <?php
    endwhile;

    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
    </section>
    <section id="skills">
    <?php
    // The Query
    query_posts( 'category_name=skills' );

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content();?></p>
    <?php
    endwhile;

    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
    </section>
    <section id="what">
    <?php
    // The Query
    query_posts( 'category_name=what i can do' );

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content();?></p>
    <?php
    endwhile;

    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
    </section>
```

**css**

```
html{font-size: 62.5%;}
#container{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:scroll;
}
#profileImg{
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/austinProfile.jpg) no-repeat center center; width:352px; height:349px;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: 0.1s;
    transition: 0.1s;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
#profileImg:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);

}
/*typography*/
#welcome h1{
    font-size: 4em;
}
#welcome p{
    font-size: 2.4em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#skills h1, #what h1{

}
/*typography*/
#welcome{float:left; width:70%; clear:none;}
#skills{clear: both;}
#what{}
```

Comment: Bro you need to work on float and width of the welcome div. This is floats property because when they dint not get enough space they just slip downwards. If you show me your working site i can solve the issue.

Comment: i can't, its in wordpress and i dont have a way to host it at the moment. thanks anyway i think i will just stick with this functionality it seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the first two sections in one container with fixed width, you won't have them misplaced when resizing the screen.

If you are trying to make a responsive layout, you can use the media queries in CSS3. See an example below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #profileImg {background-size: 50%;}
}
```